# What makes nativescript better than ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, nativescript

im new to mobile development and i see ionic framework has very big community BUT

i know that ionic uses webview while nativescript generates native components

my question now what nativescript can do ionic cannot do?

in other words what is the powerful points in nativescript that does not exists in ionic

thanks in advance.

Comment: You already mentioned the big difference, that is also where the power/weakness lies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic is hybrid, running inside webview which has problem with performance at particular things like even simpler animation, not fully accessible API of native part

Nativescript runs as native app, controlled by JS code but can be used even with native code  or even as addon to native app and full access to API of native code

Comment: thanks for reply but why no big community for nativescript like ionic

Comment: Because NativeScript is still "pretty new" and Ionic exists since 2013. NativeScript as well as React Native are totally different and new approaches to the problem of writing apps for both platforms. The NativeScript and React Native community experiences a steady growth.

Comment: And where are you looking for community? NativeScript has a pretty large slack channel.

Comment: @byemute yet somehow, React Native seems to be growing faster.